# SonarLint - show squiggly line for violations

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

What I have done: Installed SonarQube 5.6.6 locally, added checkstyle-sonar-plugin-3.6.1, connected to it from my Eclipse Neon2.Then created a project in Sonar (through mvn:clean install and sonar:sonar). The eclipse project is now bound to the Sonar project.

What happens: If there are any violations it gets reported in the Sonar alright.

What I want: Some of the violations like

```
"Abbreviation in name 'MyAPP' must contain no more than '3' consecutive capital letters."
```

are not showed as squiggly lines in Eclipse.

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SonarLint doesn't support third party analyzers such as the CheckStyle plugin. It only supports SonarSource Analyzers (SonarJS, SonarJava, ..).

More information here: http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html#FAQ